# Does Microsoft Moles support .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: compact-framework, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I am currently working on unit tests for a WinCE-based application which uses .NET Compact Framework 2.0.

I could like to know, does Moles Framework support .NET Compact Framework 2.0? If not, could someone please suggest another mocking framework that supports .NET Compact Framework?